# Finding Median in C

Tags: c, arrays, median

I wrote this code to find mean and median but I always take these errors:

> "71 warning: passing argument 1 of 'median' makes pointer from integer without a cast"

and:

> "14 note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

float mean(float x,int y)
{
float toplam = x;
int adet=y;

return toplam/adet;

}

int median(int AlinanSayilar[200],int adet)
{
int kacinci,kacinci2;
int medyan=0;

if(adet%2==1)
{
    kacinci=(adet/2)-1;
    kacinci2=kacinci+1;
    medyan=(AlinanSayilar[kacinci]+AlinanSayilar[kacinci2])/2;
}
else
{
    kacinci=(adet/2)-0.5;
    medyan=AlinanSayilar[kacinci];
}

printf("%d",medyan);

return 0;
}

int main()
{
int sayilar[200];
int i,k,j,holder;
float sum=0;

printf("Welcome the calculator...\n\tThis calculator finds mean,median and 
mode of your numbers...\n");
printf("\t\tNOTE:Please enter only integer numbers...\n\n");

for(i=0;true;i++)
{
    printf("Please enter a number(press -1 for exit): ");
    scanf("%d",&sayilar[i]);
    printf("\n");

    if(sayilar[i]==-1){
        break;
        }
    sum +=sayilar[i];
}

for(k=0;k<i-1;k++)
{
    for(j=k+1;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(sayilar[k]>sayilar[j])
        {
            holder=sayilar[k];
            sayilar[k]=sayilar[j];
            sayilar[j]=holder;
        }
    }
}

printf("Mean:%.2f",mean(sum,i));
median(sayilar[i],i);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

What should I do?Thanks in advance for your helping.And if you know finding mode(most repetitive number) could you write its code?

Comment: `sayilar[i]` is an `int`; maybe you meant: `median(sayilar[i],i);` --> `median(sayilar, i);`

Comment: It works.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Your median function takes an array and an integer, but in your main() function you called it with two ints. sayilar[i] is the i'th index of the sayilar array, so it is an int.

You can fix it by changing the line to

```
median(sayilar,i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int b[100],m,md,i,n1,md1,md2,mdt,sum,n;
int mean(int n, int a[])
{
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=a[i];
    }
    m=sum/n;
    return m;
}
int median(int n,int a[])
{
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        md1=(n/2)-1;
    md2=(n/2);
    mdt=(a[md1]+a[md2])/2;
    return mdt;


    }
    else
    {
     md=(n/2)-1;
        return a[md];
    }
}
 main()
{
    int rmean,rmedian;
    n1=10;//declaring the number of integers
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        b[i]=i+1;// assigning the integer values of the array in which mean and //median is to be found

    }
    rmean=mean(n1,b);
    rmedian=median(n1,b);
    printf("the mean :%d",rmean);
    printf("the median: %d",rmedian);
}
```